# How to encode to ascii,base64,hex from a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding

In the following code, I am converting an image file into a string depending on the choices of radio buttons:

```
def convert_now(self):  
        self.img_data = ""
        self.img_data_encoded = ""
        file1 = open(self.filedict,'rb')
        self.img_data = file1.read()

        #RADIO_BUTTONS CHOICES, Convert to: 0-ascii, 1-base64, 2-Hex
        v = self.rvar.get()
        if v==0:
            self.img_data_encoded=self.img_data
        elif v==1:
            self.img_data_encoded=base64.b64encode(self.img_data) (!)
        elif v==2:
            self.img_data_encoded=base64.b16encode(self.img_data) (!!)
```

I tried getting the base64 string from an image file using this line (!) and saved it to a "st" named string.
Then I tried getting the hex string using this one(!!)

The problem is when I compared the results I got from the code above to those I got from this website "https://www.branah.com/ascii-converter" when I used the "st"(the base64 string from the code)
they don't match at all.
Did I code something wrong ?

Comment: @Jayjayyy After I opened an image file, I wrote its data as a base64 string into a text file. I simply copied pasted the contents into the website to see what it looks like in hex. After that I tried the "base64.b16encode" and compared its result to the previous hex and they were different.  Edit: the "base64.b16encode" was used on the image file.

Comment: I uploaded a file into this site "https://www.browserling.com/tools/file-to-base64" and the base64_string I got from it matched the one I got from the above program. However, if I convert that same base64_string to hex from any website, it is different from what I get when I directly convert the file using "b16encode". EDIT: With that being said, when I tried converting the same image to hex from this website "http://tomeko.net/online_tools/file_to_hex.php?lang=en" the hex I get matches the one I get from the above program using "b16encode"

Comment: To further clarify: Let's say I have an image and I converted to base64 string named "str64". I convert the same Image to hex and I get a string named "hex1". Somehow, when I convert "str64" to hex and compare it to "hex1", they are different.

Comment: Yeah I get what you mean, I tried and it works fine with your example. I will add another question explaining in details what I'm facing.

Comment: I think it was the website: "iVBORwoaCgAAAA" (Base64) when converted using "https://www.branah.com/ascii-converter" gives something a bit off (it skips lines for no reason and removes some 0s). But when I converted it using another site, it showed the result as it should've. Your third comment was my answer all along, i'm grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't seem like you did something wrong. Your code looks fine. Also, for me, both `b64encode` and `b16encode` produce the same output as the webpage you linked to. Here is an example.

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode(b"test")
b'dGVzdA=='
>>> base64.b16encode(b"test")
b'74657374'
```

You can compare this to the results on the webpage. They match. So, there must be something else wrong. `b64encode` and `b16encode` work fine.